# Reverse part of a String

Tags: rust, concatenation, reverse, substr

I am working my way through the codefights exercises and ended up with some messy code for what, in Python, is relatively simple string slicing and concatenation:

```py
s = "the quick (brown (fox) jumps) over"
(f, t) = (18, 21)
ss = s[:f] + s[t-1:f-1:-1] + s[t:]
```

In Rust:

```
let s = String::from("the quick (brown (fox) jumps) over");
let sc: Vec<_> = s.chars().collect();
let (f, t) = (18, 21); // result of searching through sc
let mut new_s: Vec<_> = sc[..f].into_iter().collect();
new_s.extend(&sc[f..t].into_iter().rev().collect::<Vec<_>>());
new_s.extend(&sc[t..].into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>());
let mut ss = String::with_capacity(new_s.len());
for c in new_s.iter() {ss.push(**c);}
```

Mainly by adding things to fix compile errors I've ended up with complexity that I just don't seem able to reduce. What is the 'proper' way to do this in Rust?

I didn't do something like the answer using `replace()` because this is a simplified example of a problem to search through a string and reverse the parts inside matching brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should only allocate two times to your 5, I'm not sure if there is a way to get rid of the intermediate allocation:

```
let ss: String = s.chars()
                  .take(f)
                  .chain(s.chars().skip(f).take(t-f).collect::<Vec<_>>().into_iter().rev())
                  .chain(s.chars().skip(t))
                  .collect();
```

Note that UTF-8 string manipulation is a lot more complex than the Python code would seem to imply. For example, both solutions will fail to do what you expect in the presence of combining characters ([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=6a3e38b9c59c6e3b42eff8c0b0dcbde2&version=stable)).

The following gets rid of the intermediate allocation:

```
let ss: String = s.chars()
                  .take(f)
                  .chain(s.chars().rev().skip(s.chars().count()-t).take(t-f))
                  .chain(s.chars().skip(t))
                  .collect();
```

We need to use `s.chars().count()` instead of `s.len()` for Unicode, because `s.len()` is in code units and we need the length in code points.

This is easier to understand but only works for ASCII or if `f` and `t` are indices in code units:

```
let ss: String = s[..f].chars()
                       .chain(s[f..t].chars().rev())
                       .chain(s[t..].chars())
                       .collect();
```

Comment: I find it weird that one can't just do `.chain(s.chars().skip(f).take(t-f).rev())`, i.e. that `Take` doesn't implement `DoubleEndedIterator`.

Comment: Well, `Take<I>` can't implement `DoubleEndedIterator` in the general case. You would at least need `I` to be double ended itself and implement `ExactSizeIterator` so `Take` will know how much of the reversed `I` to skip. However this has suggested to me a way to avoid the allocation. I'll edit the answer in a minute.

Comment: I see what you did there, clever :).

Comment: Excellent, that's just the kind of pointer I was looking for and gives me (and other searchers on same subject) a pattern to work from. v. 1 works even for "the quick (brown (キツネ) ジャンプ) over" but v.2 and v.3 don't. However all work for the original string. The finding of f and t really need the string to iterated char by char which is why I went down the Vec<char> route. Thanks again.

Comment: I guess that's because `s.len()` is in bytes, not in characters.

Comment: @Stefan true. Replacing `s.len()` with `s.chars().count()` should allow v2 to work for unicode.

Comment: @Jmb, as the calculation of (f, t) involves iterating over the string it's probably nicer to ensure they are correct unicode char boundaries using `let ix: Vec<_> = s.char_indices().collect();` then use your option 3. Still confusing result (if correct) if there is a mixture of LtoR and RtoL unicode characters!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a single occurence of the substring (or when you want to reverse all of them):

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("the quick (brown (fox) jumps) over");
    let to_rev = &"fox";
    let ss = s.replace(to_rev, &to_rev.chars().rev().collect::<String>());

    println!("{}", ss); // the quick (brown (xof) jumps) over
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if the `to_rev` string appears more than once and you only want to replace one of them.

Comment: @interjay no it doesn't, both python 2 and 3 fail with combining characters same as all the rust versions so far.

Comment: @ljedrz, Thanks, this might have been better approach at the out-set, but I became engrossed in the question of reproducing the python style slicing and concatenation in rust. interjay, the python system seems to work ok on this computer (at least for the few japanese characters swapped as above.) Maybe that's just a fluke - I will try some more experiments.

Comment: @Jmp (& interjay) - as you say the 'working' is illusory and can easily fail in python as well as rust where there are combined unicode characters.